# How to Access Local IP url from Azure Kubernetes service?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a Kubernetes service running in Azure (AKS - Azure Kubernetes Service). It runs with the external IP. I am trying to access another service that is running in my local machine from Azure AKS.
for ex: http://:9089 (Not able to access from Azure AKS)

Is there any way where I can access my local URL from Azure AKS? Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use DynDNS or just deploy your service to another namespace within the existing AKS.